# Transaction failed with execution error while sending ether

Tags: angular, blockchain, ethereum, metamask, nft

[image: TransactionError]

I am trying to send ether using contract but it's failed to send due to some reason I am new to blockchain. can anyone please help me with the issue.

I have attached the link for Rinkeby test network transaction
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xef1d7c0fe263ab530188eef03c359c4a8acf46492213d7c20873afbbc623a101

Also attached the image for the same

Here is the contract which I have deployed

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x86eb1207a6c9868715997ebcdb53ca88020a166a#code

I am calling it from the angular as below

```
const currentContract = new ethers.Contract(
      environment.multiSendContractAddress,
      multisend_abi,
      this.signer
    );


currentContract
      .sendETH(addressArray, priceArray, {
        gasLimit: 1000000,
        value: priceValue,
      })
      .then((result: any) => {
        var resulter = {
          status: true,
          result: result,
          message: 'money send successful',
        };
        callback(resulter);
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue, Actually it's not related to code but there is minimum ether you need to send is 0.01 and I am sending the ether below 0.01 so that's why it's giving above error [Minimum ether 0.01](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015489411-How-Much-Ether-You-Need-To-Send-Tokens)